# How to return from forEach lambda while filtering over a collection of iterable element

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have one List of elements . Inside the list element in my case say `Bean` i have another list . My requirement is like , While iterating over the parent list i have to check for a specific condition in the list obtained from `Bean class getList()`and have to return a boolean from there  . Below is a demo of code what i want to achieve . How to achieve this in JAVA -8 using lambda .?

```
public boolean test(List<Bean> parentList) {

    //Bean is having another List of Bean1
    // i want to do some thing like below 
     parentList.forEach(bean ->   
      bean.getList().stream().
               filter(somePredicate).
               findFirst().isPresent();
 }
```

Comment: If the condition in one of your sublist is met the result should be true, am I right?

Comment: @Deepak please explain what exactly your code is supposed to do.  As it stands, the question is unclear

Comment: @Flown  yes if any element is preset according to predicate it will should imediately come out of the `foreach` also

Comment: @Misha  My requirement is that i want to come out of the `forEach` returning a boolean value from `test` method if during iteration over parentList i found any element list having specified criteria

Comment: @Flown  .Thank you this is just for my confirmation what i understood from flatmap operation that it will combine all the values of the sublist in to one stream and will return me back .After that i can perform any operation what i want over that stream ?

Comment: @Deepak Yes you're right. `Stream::flatMap` maps and flattens nested structures into one `Stream`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `Stream::flatMap` and check your condition:

```
parentList.stream().flatMap(bean -> bean.getList().stream()).anyMatch(somePredicate);
```